# Is angular-ui's ui-router anywhere near production ready yet?

Tags: angularjs

Our team is starting to use ui-router and it seems VERY GOOD so far. We are taking advantage of being able to fit templates into views within views. Prior to this our team was at a loss as we could not see how to get working some parts of our application that involved views inside views. We are currently using the following version:

```
 * State-based routing for AngularJS
 * @version v0.0.1 - 2013-04-15
```

There does not seem to be much commit activity lately, I don't see a roll out plan.

Is it wise or crazy to start using this code in a small application that will be in production in 3-4 months.  Does anyone have any ideas where this project is heading.  Are we crazy for using it now or should we use an alternative. If so then what is the alternative?

Comment: Do you have a link to the ui-router project?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall ui-rooter is part of the awesome angular-ui family (http://angular-ui.github.io/) and its GH repo is here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using it in a pretty big application for more than 5 months now.

It works super well and the documentation is also great.

I filled a bug when I started using it and it was resolved few days after.
I've posted some questions on their github and they were answered almost immediatly.

So yes, go on, use it. There is no better angularJS router anyway.

Comment: There is this ui-router fork but I haven't tried it : https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing

Comment: The fork is rather scary to me. So now there are two versions of ui-router :-(   Where's this heading?  I hope someone can give me some insight before the rather narrow minded people who are trying to close this question get there way. Shame really when people try to stop others from getting help.

Comment: @Anne there are not to versions of UI Router, github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing is not a fork, it's actually reuses more code from the original angular router than from UI-Router. It does however borrow on the Interface from UI-Router, since for most parts it's one of the better interfaces.